# Подскажите новичку где отрабатывать полученные знания Python

Tags: python

Читаю книгу, делаю все примеры которые в ней описываются. Вроде бы все понятно. Но хотелось бы практики. Сам себе задачи придумать не могу в силу нехватки знаний и опыта. 
Где можно тренироваться, выполнять какие- то задания/задачи начиная с 0? Что бы закреплять прочитанное.

Comment: Project Euler посмотрите, задачки там есть интересные.

Answer (score -1):

На [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/) я уже подсадил одного человека. Сам когда-то тоже прошёл с удовольствием, хоть уже и знал большую часть изложенного там.

Answer (score -1):

Можно практиковать играя в РПГ [CodeCombat](http://codecombat.com/)!
Сейчас там есть русский язык и python.

Answer (score -1):

Еще есть интересный сервис [CodeFights](https://codefights.com).

Answer (score -1):

[Checkio.org](https://www.checkio.org/)

Что-то напоминающее онлайн игру, где в качестве заданий ты должен выполнять различные упражнения, используя Python